# John P Portelli, "Upwards I Surge"

Tags: poetry, interpretation, maltese-language, john-p-portelli

This question seeks an analysis of John P. Portelli's very short poem "Nog la 'L Fuq" / "Upwards I Surge" (1977), originally written in Maltese and included with an English translation in [this book uploaded to his website](http://john-peter-portelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Bejn-Zewg-Dinjiet-Text-Copy.pdf) (where it's #32 and found on pages 74-75 of the PDF).

The poem describes surging upwards "into nebulae tinsel-like", and encountering "Monotonous piano notes / (a radio 31 emission / thousands of feet above the earth)", heading for lands "unknown but longed for". What does this describe? Is it about space travel or something more mundane? What is the purpose of the personified locations at the end (Toronto, Montreal, Malta)? This poem is the first in the "From Canada" part of his collection, so does that mean it was one of the first poems he wrote in Canada? What can we tell about his attitudes towards the different places from the way that he personifies them?

Comment: Thanks for the questions. Yes, indeed, this was the first poem I wrote on my arrival to Canada in August 1977. it is definitely a very mundane or existential piece of writing.